# Dear Fellow PSE Users,

Tags: no-computers, anagram

This puzzle is dedicated to all of you!

---

### Instructions

There are 8 anagram questions below.
In each question, you can rearrange the letters to find an answer, which is 2 English words that describe a **type of PSE users**.
These "types of PSE users" are related to the Q&A activity and other features on this site.
Note that the first letters of the answers are given inside the square brackets.
*[Updated notes] The dots in the brackets do not necessarily correspond to the position or numbers of letters.*


Let's look at a sampe question:

> Make me a ring   [E… ….]

You should find an anagram of `Make me a ring` which starts with the letter E.
The answer is `Enigma Maker`, which means someone who creates enigma / puzzles.
Now here are the questions.

### Questions

> 1. Count brown tire   [N…  ….]
> 2. Rarest red mild   [M…  ….]
> 3. Scan a queen style   [S…  ….]
> 4. Do the full rap more   [H…  ….]
> 5. Hung bad tree   [B…  ….]
> 6. My other racer   [R…  ….]
> 7. Kept near trees   [P…  ….]
> 8. No kid tired   [K…  ….]

### Rules

- You are **not allowed** to solve the anagrams using computer programs.
- Partial answers are welcome, but only full answers will be accepted.
  Please be respectful to others if you build upon their answers. :)

---

Happy solving!

Anyway, if you're still hungry for more, you can solve the…
**Bonus Question**
This question is entirely optional and will not be scored.

> A sage ruins that man   [A…  ….]

Once again, happy solving!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1 (got this and then saw Stiv's comment to that effect)

> Count brown tire = New contributor!

2

> Rarest red mild = Master riddler

3

> Scan a queen style = Sequence analyst

4 (per PilsNot3's answer)

> Do the full rap more = Helpful moderator

5 (per PilsNot3's answer / Stiv's comment)

> Hung bad tree = Badge hunter

6

> My other racer = Rhyme creator
>  
>  (Another from list of tags)

7

> Kept near trees = Pattern seeker
>  
>  (List of tags is useful!)

8

> No kid tired = Kind editor
>  
>  (I got this one only because I though the dots correspond to the number of letters in the word...)

Bonus

> A sage ruins that man = Anagram enthusiast
>  
>  (since it's a bonus, it had to do something with the puzzle itself, which is an anagram)

Comment: Nice work Mariia :) 5 is rot13(Onqtr uhagre) and 1 is rot13(Arj pbagevohgbe)

Comment: @Stiv Yes, my approach of searching for words in the list of tags doesn't work for words not on that list :-)

Comment: Knew this one would go fast :) I believe 4 is rot13(URYCSHY ZBQRENGBE)

Comment: @MariiaMykhailova Well done...! Now, please wait for some time for your green tick. Arriving soon :)